# SPFieldUserValue.User property is null for few users only

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, development, spfielduser

```
SPFieldUserValue userValue = new SPFieldUserValue(SPContext.Current.Web, DisplayName);    
SPUser user = userValue.User;
```

I wanted to fetch user from site (web) using display name and display that created by user name on a page.

But for few users, `userValue.User` is null,

If I change code to

```
SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.EnsureUser(userValue.LookupValue)
```

it is working as expected.

My concern is why `userValue.User` is null for only few users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with  [EnsureUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.ensureuser.aspx)

```
SPUser user = web.EnsureUser(userValue.LoginName);
```

Comment: Thanks Tarun, Can you explain the reason behind userValue.User is null?

Comment: Is it working for you...?

Comment: web.EnsureUser(userValue.LookupValue) is working

Comment: The reason for it being null is that the user is not in the hidden UserInfo list of the site, it is from this list the code tries to fetch the user info. Doing an `EnsureUser` makes sure the user is added to this list in the current site collection

Comment: Though user exist in user information list, it returns null for userValue.User property, can you provide relevant solution please?

Comment: any suggestions on this, still facing the issue, why User property is null